# Filtering integer array in Typescript - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array **[2, 5, 8, 12, 20, "2, 8"]**

How I can filter the integer (2), Like this **[2, "2, 8"]**

I converted my array to string and make a filter but the results are **[2, 12, 20, "2, 8"]**

This is my code

```
   this.news = this.news.filter(d => d.news_category.toString().indexOf(2) > -1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split the each array item, and see if there is a "2" value using [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
const input = [2, 5, 8, 12, 20, "2, 8"]
const output = input.filter(d => d.toString().split(",").some(val => val.trim() === "8"))

console.log(output)
```

Comment: This won't work for `8` because of space after `,`. You can `.split(/\s*,\s*/)` with an optional space on either side of comma. It will work for `2,8` or `2, 8` or  `2 ,8` or `2  ,  8`

Comment: you can use trim() method

Comment: Also, if you use the regex to get the trimmed numbers, you can directly use *includes*: `.filter( d => String(d).split(/\s*,\s*/).includes("8") )`

Comment: Thanks, Adiga, William Wang